# how to find/search the values in the list that from dictionary

Tags: python

```
laptops = {'OIS12345':['192.168.1.10', 'Windows 8', 'i7', '8GB','2.7GHz', '700GB', '15-Dec-14'],
            'OIS23415':['192.168.1.11', 'Windows 8', 'i7', '8GB','2.7GHz', '700GB', '15-Dec-14'],
            'OIS23451':['192.168.1.18', 'Windows 7', 'i5', '4GB','2.6GHz', '600GB', '13-Jan-14']}


names = laptops.keys()

attrs = laptops.values()
```

How can I check if RAM is less than 8GB and print the computer name (keys)?

I tried:

```
for i in attrs:

    match=re.search('(\d)GB',i)

    if match: 
        if match.group(2)<8:
            print names
```

Comment: Why not use nested dicts so you can do lookups by key?

Comment: this is my exercise question~*^_^* so question cant edit~:p

Comment: So you get the data like that?

Comment: yup~exam coming soon~so I find some past year question practice~

Comment: Is it always at the same index and always GB?

Comment: Yes~same index and always GB

Comment: Then the first of  the solutions below should work

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what you want:

```
for name, specs in laptops.items():
    if int(specs[3][:-2]) < 8:
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python dictionary comprehension

```
print {k for k, v in laptops.iteritems() if int(v[3][:1]) < 8}
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic solution. The `set` identifier can be removed from the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328788/removing-set-identifier-when-printing-sets-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, works with any number and GB limit.

```
for key, value in laptops.items():
    number = value[3]
    end = number.index("GB")
    if int(number[:end]) < 8:
        print(key)
```

Output:

```
OIS23451
```

You could also print out the computer keys using list comprehension:

```
print("".join([k for k, v in laptops.items() if int(v[3][:v[3].index("GB")]) < 8]))
```